# Angular 5 Interceptor doesn't intercept requests made from a library

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I have a working interceptor in Angular 5. It's registered in App.module's providers and correctly intercepts all requests made from the application.

The problem is that it doesn't intercept the requests made from the libraries used by the app.

I'm using an open source library (NGX-Jsonapi), and need the interceptor to provide a token in every request that the library makes to the back-end.

Someone faced the same issue?

EDIT: the library uses HttpClient.

Comment: Please provide some code. Specifically would like to make sure you have a single instance (singleton) of HttpClient -- rather than one with the interceptor and another that Ngx-Jsonapi service is using.

Comment: Hi Martin, what piece of code do you need? the app.module or the httpInterceptor?... I've imported httpclient in app.module, but suspect the library is using another instance, would you help me to check it? how should i proceed? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution in [Angular HttpInterceptor documentation usage notes](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor#usage-notes):

> To use the same instance of HttpInterceptors for the entire app,
>   import the HttpClientModule only in your AppModule, and add the
>   interceptors to the root application injector . If you import
>   HttpClientModule multiple times across different modules (for example,
>   in lazy loading modules), each import creates a new copy of the
>   HttpClientModule, which overwrites the interceptors provided in the
>   root module.

I was importing HttpClientModule in a lazy loaded module that was making hte requests. After resolving this issue everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

With version 4.3, angular added a new service `HttpClient`.
With version 5, angular deprecated the old service `Http`.

The interceptor only works with `HttpClient`.

You can be sure the libraries you have that are not intercepted, use the old `Http`. Pay attention, `Http` will probably be removed with angular 6!

If you want to make sure every call is intercepted by your interceptor, you need to upgrade your dependencies to their latest versions.