# Angular - using http intercecptor for authentication header jwt token in 3rd party library

Tags: angular

I've made angular jwt interceptor which implements HttpInterceptor that appends auth header with proper jwt bearer token data. There is additional logic for refreshing token.

It works OK, but now i have 3rd party library which has it's own internal logic and needs to make proper API calls to server. For example some http get request.

How can i use that same jwt interceptor logic within 3rd party library?

Comment: Try this answer here, it looks like U both have the same problem, [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794932/angular-5-interceptor-doesnt-intercept-requests-made-from-a-library)

Comment: @Nader not really - author states that library uses HttpClient. Library that use is pure javascript, no typescript, no angular at all

Comment: It was a long time ago, but did you work it out?