# Angular HTTP requests made from a library get ignored

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-library

I have refactored my Angular app by moving all business logic in a separated library in the same workspace. The datasource is now in the library and when calling `httpClient.get<whatever>('whereever')` or any other http request, it gets completely ignored. Even SVG `mat-icon`s do not make the call to retrieve the SVG (I double checked the `MatIconRegistry` and `DomSanitizer`) if used inside a component in the library.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794932/angular-5-interceptor-doesnt-intercept-requests-made-from-a-library) SO question where things gets strange if `HttpClient` gets declared multiple times in the import hierarchy, so I moved the `HttpClientModule` import in the app only, but no luck.

There is no error whatsoever in the console, which is kinda strange, and the debugger can stop on the line of the service that makes the http request but subscribing does not trigger any XHR request (which I double checked by looking at the Chrome network debug window and by setting a break point in an `HttpInterceptor` at the beginning of `intercept()`).

Any idea of what may cause the issue?

Of course all classes and respective requests where working before the refactoring.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the returned Observable, see [Angular 2 http.post() is not sending the request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36208732/1260204)? If that is not it you need to create and share a [mcve].

Comment: Of course I am subscribing! I will work on a mre as soon as I can

Comment: update your post on how your are importing the `HttpClientModule` and how your importing your Interceptor, including your Interceptor example code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a `Observable.zip` wrongly used:

```js
zip([o1, o2])
```

instead of:

```js
zip(o1, o2)
```

I took me 48h to find this issue since no error was printed out!